# Javascript callback return undefined with data

Tags: javascript, callback

i am understanding Callbacks getting return data as undefined.

```js
function goodMorning(name, msg) {
  return `${name} ${msg}`;
}

function greet(name, msg, cb) {
  const myName = "Sairam";
  console.log(`${cb(name)} ${cb(msg)} i am ${myName}`);
}

greet("Suvarna", "Good Morning", goodMorning);
```

In Above code i was passing goodMorning function as callback in greet method, while console logging return data with undefined.

[Please click here to view console message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SCSNR.png)

Comment: Your callback has 2 parameters and you call it with only one so ${msg} (in goodMorning) is undefined

Answer (score 0):

`cb (goodMorning)` is a function that gets two argument but you pass only one, you should do:

```
${cb(name, msg)}
```

Currently you call cb with only one argument instead of two so the second one gets `undefined`

Comment: Thanks for your reply arielhad, in greet function console i passed it twice once name and msg.

Comment: you need to call the function with the two arguments instead of calling it twice with 1 parameter every time